# does straight piping your car remove catalytic converters?

Tags: exhaust, dodge, catalytic-converter, charger

I have a 2014 dodge charger hemi r/t. I'm looking to make it louder and i was just concerned about the cats being removed if I straight pipe it.

Comment: Yes, it will remove the catalytic converters. If you have to pass emissions, it will no longe pass. If you want to increase your performance/noise/joy, you can replace the factory catalytic converters with high-flow catalytic converters which comply with all oppressive emissions requirements.

Comment: @the_storyteller I'll politely disagree that catalytic converters constitute "oppressive emission requirements." Without them, we'd probably be unable to breathe in Los Angeles, or to see the foothills in San Jose.

Answer (score 1):

As the_storyteller said in their comment doing this removes any catalytic converters in the replaced sections of exhaust (that's pretty much part of the definition of a "straight" pipe - it's a straight through flow!)

In the majority of locales this will lead to the car flat out failing any emissions tests, and there may be additional tests as well - in the UK for example it will additionally fail the MOT under the regulation 7.1.3:

> 3. A catalytic converter missing where one was fitted as standard

As awesome as straight pipes sound (and they do) trying to run a modern car with them on the road is impractical in most jurisdictions - the compromise option is to fit high-flowing so-called "sports" cats instead. It's not a *cheap* option, certainly when compared with just fitting straight pipes - don't expect much (if any) change from $2k by the time you've bought and fitted all three cats (inlet, driver side outlet, passenger side outlet) but it'll get you through emissions tests and should give you a noticeable increase in both sound and performance. Especially if you combine this with a wider exhaust as well (I think the stock system is only 2.5")

Answer (score 0):

Yes, straight piping removes your cats, and it is also illegal to remove your cats if your vehicle came with cats from the factory.  (I'm assuming you're in the US, since I don't expect the 2014 Dodge Charger was exported much.)

Now, if your state has no emissions testing, you may be able to get away with it, but it's still illegal.

Also, when people pull up next to or behind you at stoplights, you'll be the stinky guy.